# Does anyone have a good solution to decouple module wrappers from the parent project?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm, gulp

I've been working with [gulpjs](http://gulpjs.com) a lot recently and I'm finding myself manually decoupling a bunch of wrapper libraries from their parent projects because I don't want to be reliant on some trivial project to keep the parent project up-to-date.

For example, [gulp-jade](https://github.com/phated/gulp-jade) list `jade 1.1` as a dependency, but I want to use `1.3`, so I'm manually opening its `package.json`, removing `jade`, and removing jade from its `node_modules` directory so that it uses the `1.3` version in my project `node_modules` directory.  But now if I ever update `gulp-jade`, I have an annoying git conflict...

So I'm wondering if anyone has a solution to this that doesn't involve manually updating projects every time they're updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is mostly an issue with `gulp-jade`. Node packages in NPM stress that compliance with the [`semver`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html) spec is critical. Given that, `gulp-jade` SHOULD be using `^1.1` in the `package.json` rather than `~1.1` since it is perfectly safe as long as `jade` follows semantic versioning.

- `^1.1` means `>= 1.1.0` to `< 2.0.0`
- `~1.1` means  `>= 1.1.0` to `< 1.2.0`

In this case, I would submit a PR changing the supported version range in `gulp-jade`.

Then, to more specifically address your question, with that change, you are free to install `1.3` as a dependency of your project, alongside `gulp-jade`, and NPM will not bother installing a `1.1` version for `gulp-jade` specifically because the dependency is already satisfied by you having installed `1.3`.

#### Hacky solution

You can always add a postinstall script to your `package.json`, e.g. merge this in:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "rm ./node_modules/gulp-jade/node_modules/jade"
  }
}
```

to remove the `jade` module from `gulp-jade` when you run `npm install`. This isn't the best since you will re-install `1.1` and then promptly delete it on every install, but it is probably the simplest solution. When `node` is resolving `gulp-jade`'s dependencies, it doesn't look at versions, it will just look in the parent module's folder for a `jade` package.

Comment: Granted you're correct, but this is a problem in hundreds of npm packages and I run in to it all the time.  I could continuously fork, and submit pull requests that may be ignored forever, and just kind of always have this be a hassle.  But I'd rather find a solution that doesn't involve modifying the repo.  Besides, even if jade changes to `2.0.0`, I want to be able to update it assuming the compile API hasn't changed.  I don't want to wait for the maintainer of `gulp-jade` to do it since often-times small projects like that "just work now" and get abadoned

Comment: @zyklus True enough. I'm not sure I have a better solution for you unfortunately. The new versions of NPM are defaulting to `^` with `--save` now so hopefully that will help in the future. If you see a package doing it wrong, please file issues though so the maintainers know to consider changing the ranges. Don't assume that people won't update things. For your last point, a bump to 2.0.0 would mean an API change that would probably break gulp-jade anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to have to result to constantly wiping out `node_modules/module/node_modules/parent_project` at least for a while.  A 2.0.0 bump _probably_ wouldn't break anything with anything wrapping jade, it would break internal stuff while compiling (in a separate place from the wrapper), but jade is a bit unique here in that the compile api is dirt simple and hasn't changed in forever.

Comment: I guess you can always add a `postinstall` script to your package.json to delete the `gulp-jade` dependency. You shouldn't need to update the `gulp-jade` package.json I don't think.

Comment: accepted for the idea of a postinstall.  No idea why I didn't think of that :)